Snapping not working as expected in Blender 4.3?
Kindly see the attached video(https://youtu.be/jmTNLHcely4). Even when I've enabled snapping to vertex, and have also enabled "auto merge vertices", the snapping is not working.
Kindly help.

Put your cursor next to the vertex you want to snap and it should work

Put your cursor next to the vertex you want to snap and it should work:


Thank you so much. It did work. Earlier i was under the assumption that just when i do shift D, and move the mouse, the new object should automatically align when i move the cursor to the requisite vertex of the old object.
